# how to fine tune spacys word vectors

Tags: spacy, word-embedding

I am predicting similarities of documents using the pre trained spacy word embeddings. Because I have a lot of domain specific words, I want to fine tune my vectors on a rather small data set containing my domain specific vocabulary.

My idea was to just train the spacy model again with my data. But since the word vectors in spacy are built-in, I am not sure how to do that. Is there a way to train the spacy model again with my data?

After some research, I found out, that I can train my own vectors using Gensim. There I would have to download a pre trained model for example the Google News dataset model and afterwards I could train it again with my data set. Is this the only way? Or is there a way to proceed with my spacy model?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update: the right term here was "incremental training" and thats not possible with the pre-trained spacy models.
It is however possible, to perform incremental training on a `gensim` model. I did that with the help of another pretrained vector set (i went with the `fasttext` model) and then I trained this `gensim` model trained with the `fasttext` vectors again with my own corpus. This worked pretty well

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-trained word embeddings with fasttext in your domain and would like to use them with spaCy you can extend/replace the tokens from an existing spaCy model with your new fasttext vocabulary&vectors using something similar to this:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2538#issuecomment-404888091

or from scratch:

https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#converting

The advantage of this approach is that (1) you can keep using spacy and (2) if some tokens were present in the pre-trained spaCy but not in your corpus you will still be able to use them